# Access Arrays by index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I want to access arrays like in the example code below, this is quite slow. Is it possible to create a vector from `i` ans `f_s` and access the arrays by that index?

```
def calc(self, length):
    for i in range(int(f_s*length*6)):
        t = i / f_s  
        self.data[i] = (numpy.multiply(sinTable512[int(t*f_carrier)%512], self.Signal[int(t*f_prn)%1023]))
```

I imagine the code to look something like this:

```
def calc(self,length):
    t = numpy.arange(0, f_s*length*6, 1/f_s)
    t_sin = t * f_carrier %512
    t_sig = t * f_prn % 1023
    self.data[i] = (numpy.multiply(sinTable512[t_sin], self.Signal[t_sig]))
```

Are there any other ways to do somethink like that? From what I remember the vector operations are a lot faster than for loops, at least in MatLab, is that the same for Python or is there another method to speed this operation up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself. The solution is to use numpy's take function. You can pass the array and a vector of indices to the function and it will return the desired arrays.

```
def calc(self,length):
    t = numpy.arange(0, f_s*length*6, 1/f_s)
    t_sin = t * f_carrier %512
    t_sig = t * f_prn % 1023
    self.data = (numpy.multiply(numpy.take(sinTable512, t_sin), numpy.take(self.Signal, t_sig)))
```